# Cloud first merge into Integration - Admin stops working

Tags: admin, login, backend, cloud

Having done my first merge into integration the admin profile login screen refuses to accept the variable defined login credentials.

I could previously login into integration.

Note this is on magento-2.2 but I cannot add this tag.

Comment: Issue was that it had reverted the admin user name back to "admin" rather than the value in the cloud variable "ADMIN_USERNAME"

Answer (score 0):

Updated the cloud variables "ADMIN_USERNAME" and "ADMIN_PASSWORD" to the values that were specified before the initial merge. The merge renames the ADMIN_USERNAME back to "admin".